# Using AJAX to send create new user details via asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, .net-3.5

What's the best way to send a username and password via ajax to the code behind page in .net.

I have an index.aspx page like so:

```
                    <asp:TemplatedWizardStep>
                        <CustomNavigationTemplate>


                            <div style="margin-bottom:7px;text-align:left;">To create an account, simply send us your e-mail address. A password will be sent to this address upon submission.</div>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width:99%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;width:90px;">E-Mail:</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="newUserTextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;width:90px;padding-top:5px;">Screen name:</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;padding-top:5px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="ScreenName" runat="server" CssClass="newUserTextbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;padding-top:5px;">
                                            <asp:imagebutton ID="CreateUser" CommandName="CreateUser" Enabled="true"  runat="server" AlternateText="OK" ImageUrl="powerstats/inc/img/ok_up.png"></asp:imagebutton>

                                            <a href="javascript:InitializeLogin()"><img src="powerstats/inc/img/cancel_up.png" style="cursor:pointer;" onmouseover="SwapImageIndex(this,'cancel_ov.png')" onmouseout="SwapImageIndex(this,'cancel_up.png')" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                                   
                        </CustomNavigationTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplatedWizardStep>
```

I want the imagebutton to be clicked and send an ajax call with the username and screenname (and eventually password), to the back end page. If I do onClick=X the page refreshes. I want the page NOT to refresh and send an alert back if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use an `UpdatePanel` with a `ScriptManager`. If a submit happen inside the `UpdatePanel`, it's gonna return only what's inside the `UpdatePanel` itself through AJAX.

If you want to handle possible Error, you can use the `AsyncPostBackError Event` of the `ScriptManager`. See [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398934%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a complete exemple of error handling.

Code would look like (+ your error handling logic):

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:TemplatedWizardStep>
    <CustomNavigationTemplate>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               /* Your login controls here ...
                  Make sure to include all the fields 
                  to be refreshed + the submit button */
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </CustomNavigationTemplate>
</asp:TemplatedWizardStep>
```

Comment: so using updatepanel and a scriptmanager allows for just the panel to be updated and no page refresh?

Comment: Indeed. The UpdatePanel is the implementation of AJAX in ASP.Net. The ScriptManager creates the html script tag and all the the AJAX logic (call to the server and response).

Comment: Can I still use a client script manager in the code behind to display javascript alerts? that part doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Do you want to run javascript code only when there is an error (Look as the MSDN link) or also when the call succeed?